# Pytorch compute gradients without autograd with respect to weights

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I know the question seems like it answers itself (compute weight gradients without gradients?). But the issue I am trying to resolve is that I will need to change leaf variables before computing the backwards pass. Without no_grad pytorch will complain about in-place modifications.

1. Define the model (it is split in two stages of a pipeline):

```py
class Pipe1(nn.Module):
      def __init__(self):
        super(Pipe1, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)

      def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2(x), 2))
        return x
 class Pipe2(nn.Module):
     def __init__(self):
        super(Pipe2, self).__init__()
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)

     def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1, 320)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x)
```

2. Make the pipeline:

```py
pipe = [Pipe1(), Pipe2()]
```

3. Run a micro-batch through the pipeline:

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
      output = pipe [1](pipe [0](data))
      
      loss = F.nll_loss(output, target)
      pipe[0].conv1.weight *= 3
```

And... what is four? Given the current loss I would ideally want to compute the derivatives with respect to the new updated weights. Is there any "proper" way of doing this in Pytorch? Would I need to compute the gradients myself? I would prefer if I wouldn't need to do that per type of layer.

The Jacobian computes the gradient with respect to the inputs, so that won't be useful.

I am well aware that the activations which are passed to the second stage of the pipeline (Pipe2) are computed on weights different than those on which I compute the gradients for on Pipe1. This is intended behaviour (see [Pipemare](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.05124.pdf))

Best I can come up with is the following (disgusting) solution

1. Do not get gradient on first stage, keep gradient on first stage output (second stage input) and compute loss

```py
 with torch.no_grad():
        inpt_tmp = pipe [0](data)
 inpt_tmp.requires_grad = True
 output = pipe (inpt_tmp)
 loss = F.nll_loss(output, target)
 loss.backward()
 optimizers[1].step()
```

2. Update parameter, run new forward pass and use the output (with external gradient the gradient of the old output) to compute a new backwards pass:

```py
with torch.no_grad():
   pipe[0].conv1.weight *= 3
tmp = pipelines[batch_idx % modulo][0](data)
tmp.backward(inpt_tmp.grad)
```

This requires 2 forward passes on the first stage.

Comment: Why does the update need to be an in-place operation? And when you say `compute the derivatives with respect to the new updated weights` do you mean compute the gradients of operations prior to the weight update after the weight has been updated? Because this is not possible.

Comment: No I mean compute the new gradient with respect to the UPDATED weights (see pipemare for the reasoning)! It should be in place to reduce memory overhead of storing multiple parameters. @Karl